# Activating Julia virtual environments

Tags: julia

I'm trying to figure out how Julia packages work since I like having containerized environments. I'm really struggling with it.

In python, I'd do something like `conda create env --name ds` to make an environment and then to install containerized packages I'd use `conda activate ds; conda install <packages>`.

I'm not having much success trying to get Julia to make a virtual environment.

From the Julia REPL I can type `]` to go to package managers then I can create an enviornment with `activate ds`. From here I can add important packages `add IJulia DataFrames Plots`

At this point, my environment becomes actual folders which is good.

What I then don't know how to do is to activate my environment so that I can then run `using IJulia; notebook()`

From the REPL if I type `activate ds` it doesn't know what I'm talking about, even if I do `cd("ds"); activate .` it still doesn't know what I'm trying to do...

I looked at the docs and it seems to detail out how to manipulate packages but I haven't found anything helpful for actually running them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write `activate ds` (or `activate .` if you are already in the `ds` directory) in the package manager mode that is started with `]` as you have commented.

Alternatively you can activate environments when you start Julia. Just write

```
julia --project=.
```

(if you are already in the `ds` directory).

Here https://github.com/bkamins/PyDataGlobal2020 you have a step by step example how to run things for a sample project.

A third option is to activate the environment via the package manager API e.g. like this

```
using Pkg
Pkg.activate(".")
```